# Chroot user VSFTPD, can't enter Folder

Tags: nginx, ftp, centos7, vsftpd

I'm trying to enter a NGINX folder,
via Filezilla with my local user.

The OS of my server is CentOS 7.
I installed vsftpd on it this way:

```
#Install VSFTP
sudo yum -y install vsftpd
#Make Log file
sudo mkdir /var/log/vsftpd
sudo touch /var/log/vsftpd/vsftpd.log
sudo chmod 0777 /var/log/vsftpd/vsftpd.log
#Make SSL/TLS certificate; Pem file
sudo openssl req -x509 -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.pem -out /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.pem
#Update the SELinux boolean values for FTP service;  getsebool -a | grep ftp
sudo setsebool -P ftp_home_dir on
#Place "free" Users in Allow list
sudo echo "bla_user" > /etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
```

This is my /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf file:

```
#Banner
ftpd_banner=Welcome to FTP service
#Pam service name
pam_service_name=vsftpd
#Tuning FTP users
anonymous_enable=NO
#Connect Local users; TLS/SSL/FTPS
local_enable=YES
#Check shell
check_shell=NO
#Write permissions
write_enable=YES
#Enable Chroot; Some Users are "free"
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
#List of "free" Users
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
#Root dir
local_root=/usr/share/nginx/html/
#Ascii mode
ascii_upload_enable=YES
ascii_download_enable=YES
#Enable TLS/SSL
ssl_enable=YES
#Force Users to use TLS encryption
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
#Specify SSL certificate/private key; Pem file
rsa_cert_file=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.pem
#Define port range for Passive mode connections
pasv_max_port=51000
pasv_min_port=50000
pasv_address=<My router IP>
pasv_addr_resolve=NO
#Client session is timed out after 300 seconds
idle_session_timeout=300
#Maximum number of connections per IP, helps against DoS/DDoS attacks
max_per_ip=50
#Show hidden files and the "." and ".." folders
force_dot_files=YES
#Use localtime
use_localtime=YES
#Make files Executable
file_open_mode=0777
#Enable logging
xferlog_enable=YES
xferlog_std_format=NO
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd/vsftpd.log
log_ftp_protocol=YES
debug_ssl=YES
```

I made a directory for a chrooted user (this one should not be free) ect., like this:

```
#Make dir
sudo mkdir /usr/share/nginx/html/test_user
#Make SFTP User
sudo useradd -d /usr/share/nginx/html/test_user -s /usr/sbin/nologin test_user
#Define Password
sudo passwd ksuser
#Place ftp user in NGINX group
sudo usermod -aG nginx test_user
```

Then I started the services like this:

```
#Start services
sudo systemctl start vsftpd
sudo systemctl enable vsftpd
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=21/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=ftp
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=51000/tcp
#Restart firewall
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

But when I try to login in with Filezilla, I get:

```
230 Login successful, 200 PROT now Private ect.
```

But in the end I got:

```
Connection lost, and Receiving folders failed
```

---

I tried opening my ports and reloaded my firewall, suggested by HBruijn.
Also I run these commands, given by running audit2why suggested by Mircea:

```
#Allow access
sudo setsebool -P nis_enabled 1
#Allow ftpd to connect all unreserved
sudo setsebool -P ftpd_connect_all_unreserved 1
```

I still can't enter my folder.
Can it be my router, or should I turn more on with setsebool?
This is my boolean list:

```
ftp_home_dir --> on
ftpd_anon_write --> off
ftpd_connect_all_unreserved --> on
ftpd_connect_db --> off
ftpd_full_access --> off
ftpd_use_cifs --> off
ftpd_use_fusefs --> off
ftpd_use_nfs --> off
ftpd_use_passive_mode --> off
httpd_can_connect_ftp --> off
httpd_enable_ftp_server --> off
sftpd_anon_write --> off
sftpd_enable_homedirs --> off
sftpd_full_access --> off
sftpd_write_ssh_home --> off
tftp_anon_write --> off
tftp_home_dir --> off
```

Answer (score 2):

You define a passive port range of 50000-51000 in the vsftpd.conf but only explicitly open a single port 51000 in your firewall configuration.

Since you're using TLS to secure the connection the normal netfilter FTP helper module can't dynamically open the related passive port.

Solution: open the correct port range.

```
 sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=50000-51000/tcp
```

Comment: Okay, I tried that and reloaded my firewall.
Still not working :/

Answer (score 0):

First you should rule out a SELinux problem. Search /var/log/audit/audit.log for ftp entries:

```
audit2why < /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

Check the vsftpd logs for any errors.

If nothing is working use `strace` on vfstp and try to figure out where is failing.

Which SELinux context is set for /usr/share/nginx/html/ file? Run the following command to see this:

```
ls -lZd /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

Comment: With the first command I got:
Was caused by.. Allow nis to enabled (nis_enabled), Allow access by executing (ftpd_connect_all_unreserved).
I should run this with setsebool?

Second command I got:
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0       /usr/share/nginx/html/